# How to get desired DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

In a Document Object Model tree, there are few DOMs with the same ID. But one of them is visible but the others are not. In this case, how can I only access or manipulate the visible or active ID?

Comment: How can you have duplicate ids?

Comment: It is not the right way to have same id's for multiple elements, instead you can have same classes for multiple elements

Comment: How element is being activated ? Using `click` event ? If yes then use `this` or `event.target`. There are many ways to do so but not without seeing your code.. __You can not have multiple elements having same `id` property in `DOM`__

Comment: What does "active or shown" mean in this context?

Comment: @Quentin active or shown means what i see in the page.

Comment: @Yusuf please check RayonDabre comment.

Comment: @Yusuf — So you want to test for all of "Not display: none, visibility: visible, scrolled to in the viewport, scrolled to in any ancestor with overflow set, not covered up by an absolutely, relatively, or fixed positioned element"? Can't you narrow that down?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, What is there to be checked ? Will you mind explaining a bit ?

Comment: @RayonDabre My last comment is for Yusuf.

Comment: I know its not a good practice to add element with same id in a page.  But somehow the build system generate it. Ok now am explaining the problem with an example: there are five elements with same Id: casteListID. Four of them have display none so they are not shown in the page. One of them have display inline property. when i want to add few options(select) in the DOM element  which is shown in the page. It add options in one of the element which are not shown in the page. i think this is good enough for an expert.

Comment: @Yusuf — So all you want to test if what their display property is set to?

Answer (score 2):

`id` **must** be unique in same document, try to replace duplicate ids by global `class`, then you can use class selector and `is(":visible")` to check if the element is visible.

I'm not sure where you want to use it (there o context in your OP), I guess you want to use it in click event :

```
$('.global_class').click(function(){
     $(this).is(":visible");
})
```

If you can not change those ids, try to select them using attribute selector, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('[id="casteListID"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).is(':visible');
}).append('<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='casteListID' style='display: none'>div 1</div>
<div id='casteListID'>div 2 </div>
<div id='casteListID' style='display: none'>div 3</div>
<div id='casteListID' style='display: none'>div 4</div>
<div id='casteListID' style='display: none'>div 5</div>
```

Comment: While this is good advice, it doesn't answer the question (which is how to determine which one is "shown"), so should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It is very appreciable if you answer raw JS context.